# hide and unhide button in jQuery

Tags: jquery, hide

I have a small script here. When you press the button the text hides. If I would like to change the text to `"unhide"` when the text is gone, how can I do this?

I mean so the text on the button changes to `"unhide"`.

```
<div>
   <p>Should I hide this message?</p>
   <button>Click for hide</button>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function() {
      $('p').slideToggle();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: [Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/ATYwM/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should:

- Give an `id` to your `<p>`
- Give an `id` to your `<button>`
- Leverage the visiblity of the `<p>` to change the text

Your code would become

```
<div>
   <p id="theMessage">Should I hide this message?</p>
   <button id="theButton">Click for hide</button>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    // $('button') would attach it to ALL buttons on page
    // this would attach it only to the correct one
    $('#theButton').click(function() {
      var _this = this;
      var pTag = $('#theMessage');
      pTag.slideToggle(function(){
        // avoiding else block through initialization
        var buttonText = "Click to unhide";
        if(pTag.is(':visible')) {
            buttonText = "Click to hide";
        }
        // note this is '_this' from the .click handler
        _this.text(buttonText);
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Watch out for the ternary operator `?:`, *both* sides are evaluated so you might experience obscure side effects in your code. `if/else` keeps you safe from this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Use condition with ternary operator `? :` to change the text, if text is `Click for hide` we will change it to `Click for unhide` otherwise we will change it to `Click for hide`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7feW7/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function() {
        $(this).text($(this).text() ==  "Click for hide" ? "Click for unhide" : "Click for hide");
        $('p').slideToggle();

    });
});
```

**Edit** as @Alex pointed out this solution is not very friendly if the text is updated and might have typo. You can use the visibility of `p` to change the text. Also using  `$('p').slideToggle();` will effect all the `p` on the page. You should relate it to `p` before `button`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7feW7/1/)**

```
 $('button').click(function () {
      $(this).text($(this).prev().is(":visible") ? "Click for unhide" : "Click for hide");
      $(this).prev().slideToggle();
 });
```

Comment: This is logically wrong (button text isn't actually relying on the visibilty of the `<p>`) and annoying to mantain if the need to change the button text arises (i.e. localization). A typo in a label would make it non-functional.

Comment: Defintely better, but ... what if something is added between the button and the <p>, or the <p> is wrapped in a container ?

Comment: Well we have to stop at some point. The one who is changing html/javascript (code) should know what could be impact.

Answer (score 2):

You could check for `:visible`:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6E777/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        var $self = $(this);
        $(this).closest('div').find('p').slideToggle(function () {
            $self.text($(this).is(':visible') ? "Click for hide" : "unhide");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: There is a little catch: this would apply to all `<p>` in the page. If another one is added, it would also appear/disppear.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function() {
        $('p').slideToggle(function() {
            $('button').text('new text');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: OMG that was some quick answers. Thanks a lot everybody. I used this code

Comment: This would change the paragraph's text and the OP wants the button text to change.

Comment: @user1883095 Adil's answer would account for switching it back to the initial text too =)

Comment: OK, now you're fixed your mistake, but the text now doesn't change back. Adil's answer is best.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div>
    <p style="display:block">Should I hide this message?</p>
    <button>Click for hide</button>
</div>
   $( "button" ).click(function() {
    $( "p" ).toggle(function(){
        $("button").text($(this).is(':visible') ? "Click for hide" : "unhide");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fbBRV/

**Updated code and jsfiddle.**

Answer (score -2):

The best code for me who solved it was:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function() {
        $('p').slideToggle(function() {
            $(this).text('new text');
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks a lot everybody for the answers :-)

Comment: You don'/shouldn't re-post the answer of the person you chose to use. Simply select their answer by accepting it by clicking the check next to it. Also, the answer you chose is wrong.

Comment: And so what happen when you reclick button?